# Set the orientation to portrait from code

Tags: android, orientation, manifest, screen-orientation, portrait

I know I can limit the orientation from the manifest file. Like this

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

But is it possible to set the orientation from code ?

for example setting the activity to full screen can be done both from manifest and from code `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: Check : http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Activity. setRequestedOrientation(..)
```