# How to show custom dialog in portarit mode only in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

Hi I don't want to set activity orientation I want to restrict only dialog.
Let me know is it possible.

**

> Only for Dialog not Activity

.**

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(context);
    Window window = d.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //d.setCancelable(false);
    d.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main_for_printing);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    lp.screenOrientation=WindowManager.LayoutParams./// Here how to set orentation
    d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035453/set-the-orientation-to-portrait-from-code?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Why not just make a new Activity and use a dialog style?

Comment: Hi is it possible to set orentation at this line:-lp.screenOrientation=WindowManager.LayoutParams.

Comment: If I open dialog then my dialog should be in portrait mode and if I close dialog then my activity support both orentation. Also I have added one line in my edited question :-lp.screenOrientation=ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the orientation in that place where you want to show a dialog.

- case 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2799001/3864698
- case 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14929272/3864698

If orientation is portrait then show your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1: make your activity portrait through manifest using screen orientation

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

STEP 2: where ever required create dialog as below

```
Dialog dialogBoxAbout = new Dialog(this);
dialogBoxAbout.setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
dialogBoxAbout.show();
```

This is for making a dialog through XML.

**ANOTHER OPTION** 
Create a new activity and make it a dialog.
Declare it in manifest file as mentioned below.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.dialog"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To lock orientation
`if (activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }`

TO unlock :

```
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```