# How to call setRequestedOrientation() from cpp file?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, orientation, openframeworks

I'm trying to limit available orientation in Android.
It works well by setting the below flag on manifest file.

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

But I would like to set it by coding.
I found this question from the link below.

[Set the orientation to portrait from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035453/set-the-orientation-to-portrait-from-code)

And it says I can set it with the following code.

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

But I'm using C++ based frameworks called openFrameworks for Android development and I have no idea how to call this method from ofApp.cpp file.
Can someone please teach me how to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the whole explanation [Android Rotation Exploitation](http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2012/09/android-rotation-exploitation.html), the [source code](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/97874334/Native_getRotation.tgz) and the [video](https://youtu.be/oRzOweLD6ik). I hope this helps